# Why is the elements being replaced instead of appended?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am reading a very large json file and pulling in data. I can currently pull in the correct data, but when I try and append it to an array, it ends up replacing it.

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON){

    let predicate = {
        (json: JSON) -> Bool in
        if let jsonID = json["class"].string where jsonID == "sg-header-heading"{

            return true

        }
        return false
    }
    var backclass = ViewController()
    let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(backclass, predicate: predicate)
```

Using this extension to search for multiple values that match "sg-header-heading"
When I print the array in the extension this is what I get. But when I print it above I get nil. Also I am only getting one value per instead of 6 values in the end.

[image]

```
extension JSON{

func findmultiple(viewclass: ViewController, @noescape predicate: JSON -> Bool) -> JSON? {

   var backclass = ViewController()

    if predicate(self) {
        return self
    }
    else {
        if let subJSON = (dictionary?.map { $0.1 } ?? array) {
            for json in subJSON {

                if let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(backclass, predicate: predicate) {
                    let shorten = foundJSON["html"].stringValue
                    let firstshort = shorten.componentsSeparatedByString("   ")
                    let secondshort = firstshort[1].componentsSeparatedByString("\r")
                    let classname = secondshort[0]
                    if(classname == "STUDY HALL (INSTRUCT)"){
                        print("skip")
                    }else{
                        backclass.importClass.append(classname)
                        print("fsgsfg \(backclass.importClass)")
                        //backclass.collection.reloadData()
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
}
```

Comment: when you recursive , backclass Initializes a lot of time, isn't it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are first calling `findmultiple()` from the outermost context (`let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(predicate)`).  As the code is executed and `findmultiple()` is actually executed it creates a new instance of with `var backclass = ViewController()`.  As the code goes into its loop it executes `findmultiple()` again, recursively.  As the code goes into its loop an additional time it creates a new instance of `backclass`.  Each time it goes through the loop, the recursion goes deeper and a new instance of `ViewController` is created each time so `backclass` always points to a new instance of `ViewController`.

The solution to this would be to create `backclass` at a higher level. You might try an approach like this:

```
var backclass = ViewController()
let foundJSON = json.findmultiple(backclass, predicate)
```

Note that this would mean passing `backclass` to `findmultiple` from inside the loop where the recursive call happens.

Comment: How would I add the parameter in the function? Something like this? http://puu.sh/p34xv/0495baf411.png

Comment: I *think* it goes like this: `func findmultiple(viewclass: ViewController, @noescape predicate: JSON -> Bool) -> JSON? {
`

Comment: I have the full array http://puu.sh/p39Ta/d26a1d9b8b.png, but when I try and reload the collection view it crashes with the error `index out of range`, and when I printed `importClass.count` I get 0. I printed it in the same class the collection view is in.